# Wordpress PHP: Unexpected $End Error

Tags: php, syntax

This is both my first time messing with a Wordpress Template and my first time using PHP (save for the occasional server include).  Which is to say, I no nothing of PHP and only barely have a grasp on the syntax.

I'm trying to create some customized loops and once I got one to work, I simply copy pasted the working code, changed the ID's, and expected that to work. Silly maybe?  Anyhow, I'm getting an unexpected $end on line 203.

Anyone willing to tell me what's causing that? Thanks in advance!

```
<!-- FEATURED LOOP -->
<div class="featured">
<?php $my_query = new WP_Query('category_name=featured&showposts=1'); ?>
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>
    <?php while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post(); ?>

        <?php do_atomic( 'before_entry' ); // origin_before_entry ?>

        <div id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" class="<?php hybrid_entry_class(); ?>">
            <?php do_atomic( 'open_entry' ); // origin_open_entry ?>

            <?php
            if ( current_theme_supports( 'get-the-image' ) ) {                              
                if ( is_sticky ( $post->ID ) ) {
                    get_the_image( array( 'meta_key' => 'Thumbnail', 'size' => 'single-thumbnail', 'image_class' => 'featured' ) );
                } else {
                    get_the_image( array( 'meta_key' => 'Thumbnail', 'size' => 'thumbnail', 'image_class' => 'featured' ) );
                }
            }
            ?>

            <div class="sticky-header">
                <?php echo apply_atomic_shortcode( 'entry_title', '[entry-title]' ); ?>
                <?php echo apply_atomic_shortcode( 'byline', '<div class="byline">' . __( '[entry-published] &middot; by [entry-author] &middot; in [entry-terms taxonomy="category" before=""] [entry-edit-link before=" &middot; "]', 'origin' ) . '</div>' ); ?>                 
            </div><!-- .sticky-header -->

            <div class="entry-summary">
                <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
                <?php wp_link_pages( array( 'before' => '<p class="page-links">' . __( 'Pages:', 'origin' ), 'after' => '</p>' ) ); ?>
            </div><!-- .entry-summary -->

            <?php do_atomic( 'close_entry' ); // origin_close_entry ?>
        </div><!-- .hentry -->

        <?php do_atomic( 'after_entry' ); // origin_after_entry ?>

    <?php endwhile; ?>
    <?php wp_reset_postdata(); // reset the query ?>
<?php else : ?>
<!--END FEATURED LOOP-->    

<!-- SUBFEATURED LOOP -->
<div class="subfeatured">
<?php $my_query = new WP_Query('category_name=subfeatured&showposts=1'); ?>
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>
    <?php while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post(); ?>

        <?php do_atomic( 'before_entry' ); // origin_before_entry ?>

        <div id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" class="<?php hybrid_entry_class(); ?>">
            <?php do_atomic( 'open_entry' ); // origin_open_entry ?>

            <?php
                if ( current_theme_supports( 'get-the-image' ) ) {
                    if ( is_sticky ( $post->ID ) ) {
                        get_the_image( array( 'meta_key' => 'Thumbnail', 'size' => 'single-thumbnail', 'image_class' => 'featured' ) );
                    } else {
                        get_the_image( array( 'meta_key' => 'Thumbnail', 'size' => 'thumbnail', 'image_class' => 'featured' ) );
                    }
                }
            ?>

            <div class="sticky-header">
                <?php echo apply_atomic_shortcode( 'entry_title', '[entry-title]' ); ?>
                <?php echo apply_atomic_shortcode( 'byline', '<div class="byline">' . __( '[entry-published] &middot; by [entry-author] &middot; in [entry-terms taxonomy="category" before=""] [entry-edit-link before=" &middot; "]', 'origin' ) . '</div>' ); ?>
            </div><!-- .sticky-header -->

            <div class="entry-summary">
                <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
                <?php wp_link_pages( array( 'before' => '<p class="page-links">' . __( 'Pages:', 'origin' ), 'after' => '</p>' ) ); ?>
            </div><!-- .entry-summary -->

            <?php do_atomic( 'close_entry' ); // origin_close_entry ?>
        </div><!-- .hentry -->

        <?php do_atomic( 'after_entry' ); // origin_after_entry ?>

    <?php endwhile; ?>  
    <?php wp_reset_postdata(); // reset the query ?>
<?php else : ?>         
<!--END SUBFEATURED LOOP-->
```

Comment: Usually that error indicates that you're missing the closing of a loop (for, foreach, while, if). Can you check before/after line 203 to see if that is the case? It's a bit difficult to sort through it all, without the line numbers.

Comment: Vote to close as Too Localized. It's easy to tell what that error means from the [4,000+ other questions](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bphp%5D+Unexpected+%24End+Error). You have a mis-matched control structure somewhere.

Comment: If you replace both of the `<?php else : ?>` lines in the code with `<?php endif; ?>` you should be good to go.

Answer (score 3):

The last line of php code you have is:

```
   <?php else : ?>
```

You need to complete that [control structure](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php). You are missing something like:

```
   <?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Found it! Sorry about the naiveté of this question, Php fries my non-developer brain.  Many thanks!